# collapse bootstrap function and dropdowns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the collpase bootstrap function and am having a display problem with the function Dropdowns.

[Here](http://s168768764.onlinehome.fr/bootstrap/) is my demo.

Click on the + (plus) sign, then click on the link titled Dropdown. You will see that the submenu is hidden. How can I make it appear in the foreground?

Thank you

Comment: Add 412's answer to your `<style>.collapse.in {
    overflow: visible;
}</style>`  inside your style tags.

Comment: Yeah i'm seeing that the `+` is bouncing I don't remember seeing that before. But the `answer` is not what is causing the issue.  That is probably something you would need to ask another question if you need help addressing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `overflow: hidden;` rule on `.collapse` - since you don't want the menu to be visible before a user clicks the **"+"** icon, you can add `overflow: visible;` to `.collapse.in` once it's been toggled:

```
.collapse.in {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: There are no other solution to hide and display my menu with bootstrap?

Comment: Take away the `position:relative` (the Jquery in my previous answer - now deleted) from your site and add this css.

Comment: ok I add .collapse.in {overflow: visible;} and deled $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.dropdown-menu').css('position','relative');
}); is work but look the +